# Boggeled by binary bit conversions

Tags: binary, int

I found and modified an int-to-bin converter that seems to be working right.  Then I put together a bin-to-int converter but the result shows that im reading the binary backwards.  I reversed the direction of the for loop: for(i = 11; i >=0; i--), but got the same result.

```
@implementation MainViewController

- (void)intToBin:(int)theNumber
{
    NSMutableString *str = [NSMutableString string];
    NSInteger numberCopy = theNumber;
    for(NSInteger i = 0; i <= 11 ; i++)
    {
        [str insertString:((numberCopy & 1) ? @"1" : @"0") atIndex:0];
         numberCopy >>= 1;
    }
    NSLog(@"Binary version: %@", str);
}

- (void)binToInt:(NSString *)theBinary
{
    int decNumber = 0;
    int i; 
    for(i = 0; i <=11; i++)   // then tried: for(i = 11; i >=0; i--)
    {
        NSString *digitChar = [theBinary substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (i, 1)];
        int digitNum = [digitChar intValue];
        NSLog(@"digitNum: %d", digitNum);
        if(digitNum == 1) decNumber += digitNum * pow(2,i);
    }
    NSLog(@"Decimal version: %d", decNumber);       
}
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self intToBin:3434];
    [self intToBin:3418];
    [self intToBin:2906];

    [self binToInt:@"110101101010"];
    [self binToInt:@"110101011010"];
    [self binToInt:@"101101011010"];

}
```

Log Details:

```
[Session started at 2011-03-23 22:05:30 -0500.]
Binary version: 110101101010
Binary version: 110101011010
Binary version: 101101011010
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
Decimal version: 1387
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
Decimal version: 1451
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
Decimal version: 1453





[Session started at 2011-03-23 22:06:46 -0500.]
Binary version: 110101101010
Binary version: 110101011010
Binary version: 101101011010
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
Decimal version: 1387
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
Decimal version: 1451
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 1
digitNum: 0
digitNum: 1
Decimal version: 1453
```

What did I miss?  Is there a better way to do this without using hex?  Or with...

Thanks in advance for the assist.
MP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether you iterate the string from 0 to 11 or 11 to 0, `decNumber += digitNum * pow(2,i)` sets the bit based on the character index. The quick fix is to use `pow(2,11-i)` instead, so position 11 in the string gets 2**0, position 10 gets 2**1, and so on.

A better way to do it, though, would be like this:

```
int decNumber = 0;
int i; 
for(i = 0; i <=11; i++)
{
    NSString *digitChar = [theBinary substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (i, 1)];
    int digitNum = [digitChar intValue];
    NSLog(@"digitNum: %d", digitNum);
    decNumber = (decNumber << 1) | (digitNum == 1 ? 1 : 0);
}
```

As it processes each digit in the string, the `(decNumber << 1)` shifts all the previously-handled bits over by 1 and the `| (digitNum == 1 ? 1 : 0)` sets the lowest bit in the number to 0 or 1 based on the character just read. It could certainly be improved further, for example by more efficiently parsing the string, but I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Thanks, this also worked but I'm not sure how.  Could you expound a little or suggest a link?  I'll be working with allot of this type of code and I thought binary would be as concise as it gets.  Having to convert to and from strings really destroys any advantages I thought I'd find.

Comment: There's a difference between "binary", the internal representation used for everything, and "binary encoded as a string of 0s and 1s", which is among the least concise representations.

Answer (score 0):

You're using strings to represent numbers, that's probably not a good way to solve what you're trying to do. But however, to answer your question, you're raising the wrong index to the power of 2. Regardless in which way you're counting your loop, you're still multiplying by the same indeces. As you start reading the string, the *first* digit will be most significant. You can solve this problem by

- first reversing the binary string, or
- using an alternate strategy to get at your decimal number. (i.e using multiplies and adds versus using `pow`)

Your fixed loop can look like (**warning, untested**):

```
...
for(i = 0; i <=11; i++)   // then tried: for(i = 11; i >=0; i--)
{
    int digitNum = [[theBinary substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (i, 1)] intValue];
    NSLog(@"digitNum: %d", digitNum);
    decNumber = decNumber * 2 + digitNum;
}
...
```

FYI, this code is unnecessary at best and unclear at worst. You can also accomplish the above multiply+add with a simple shift and add.

Comment: Thanks Yan it worked but I ended up using the code from Anomie as it reflects the changes you both suggested.